# Get current lat and lng from Google Geolocation API

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I have no problem getting the current lat and lng using javascript. But I would like to call the API link in PHP via file_get_contents as following:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=Jsddds6s6sdht43asdsaASasta8962');
?>
```

Current if I paste the URL in Chrome, I am getting **Not Found**. Why does this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its giving error because your are use query string GET method for it**

**use POST method to retrieve data because google geolocation only allows post method**
[image]
**here is an example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Geocode  Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<span>Your Latitude : </span><span id="lat"></span><br>
<span>Your Longitude : </span><span id="lng"></span><br>
<button id="btn">Click Here To Get Lat And Lng</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(e) {
         $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  data: '', 
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyCW0lvagDP67ulkwwP7yAIBHJoj2HT0apM", 
  success: function(result){
          $('#lat').html(result['location']['lat']);
    $('#lng').html(result['location']['lng']);
     
      }});
     
    });
} );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Often we overlook the simplest notice.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check the response you get from the API.

```
function get_http_response_code($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}
if(get_http_response_code('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=Jsddds6s6sdht43asdsaASasta8962') != "200"){
    echo "Error parsing api";
}else{
    file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=Jsddds6s6sdht43asdsaASasta8962');
}
```

Refer [Dev Guid for Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Or, you might try using this -

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=Jsddds6s6sdht43asdsaASasta8962');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

So this should give you a json string and then you can manipulate it by decoding.

Comment: I know it is giving me error because I directly pasted the URL in the address bar. one of the reason i am doing this is because i do not wish to code javascript :(

Comment: Updated my answer